# How to calculate positive and negative polygonal areas between two lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to calculate the net change in a land-surface from a cross-sectional survey over time.

I have points and a line for each survey and I'm interested in finding the area between these lines. However, I want to calculate areas as positive ("fill") or negative ("cut") depending on which survey-line is on top, representing whether there was a gain or loss in the land-surface. Furthermore, these surveys typically result in a complex polygon, with cut and fill both occurring in the same survey at different locations.

Sadly, start and end points of each survey are different, so I cannot just subtract Y-values at each X. I'm interested in the true area when connecting start and end-points together as a polygon.

I have had some success calculating the total polygonal area between the lines, but am completely stumped on how to use polygons and areas with positive and negative areas.

Some example data and a plot showing what I'm trying to calculate is below:

```
x1 <- c(1.5, 2.3,3,3.2,4.1, 5)
y1 <- c(6, 4.5, 3, 2.5, 1.1,0.7)
x2 <- c(0.5,1.5, 2.5, 3.7, 5, 5.7)
y2 <- c(5.5, 4.5, 3.2, 2.5, 1.5,0.9)
lines <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, y1, x2, y2))

poly_lines <- rbind(setNames(lines[,1:2],c('x','y')),
                 setNames(lines[6:1,3:4],c('x','y')))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(lines) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x1, y=y1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x2, y=y2)) +
  geom_polygon(data = poly_lines, aes(x = x,y = y), fill = "grey")+ 
  theme_classic()+
  geom_point(aes(x=x1, y=y1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x2, y=y2)) +
  xlab("x")+
  ylab("y")
```

Example image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: you have `poly_df` which is not defined

Comment: @Al14: Changing 'poly_df' to 'poly_lines' fixes that problem. Pretty sure the problem reduces to calculating the intercept, calculating individual polygon areas (which ISTR is an easy to solve problem) and deciding on a sign for the addition based on a single x variable in the middle of each  convex polygon. I suspect the 'sp' package (or one of its "geo"-friends) has a method.